# Transfer data from one table to another identical table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [db1].[dbo].Subscriber ON

INSERT INTO [db1].[dbo].Subscriber
    SELECT * FROM [db2].[dbo].SubScriber

PRINT 'Successfully Re-imported data from SubScriber backup'

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [db1].[dbo].Subscriber OFF
```

All I want is a dynamic way to copy data from one table that has an identical setup as another table in another database but I continue to get this error:

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'db1.dbo.MsSubProject' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

I have already explicitly set the IDENTITY_INSERT to ON.
Also, even when I try explicitly write out the table columns like so:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [db1].[dbo].Subscriber ON

INSERT INTO [db1].[dbo].Subscriber (SubscriberGUID, ItemGUID_Entity, SubscriberID, SubscriberRegionID, SubscriberTypeID, ID, SubscriberNameFull, SubscriberEmail, SubscriberLogin, SubscriberPassword, Active, DateCreated, DateDeleted)
    SELECT * FROM [db2].[dbo].SubScriber

PRINT 'Successfully Re-imported data from SubScriber backup'

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [db1].[dbo].MsSubscriber OFF
```

This also doesn't work...

What am I doing wrong? Every solution I've found on StackOverflow for this specific issue doesn't work for me.

Comment: *"This also doesn't work..."* So what happens when do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **also** get in the habit of using **explicit column lists** in your `SELECT` statements! `SELECT *` is OK for querying ad-hoc style in SSMS - but it should be **banned** from use in any production code!

Try this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [db1].[dbo].Subscriber ON

INSERT INTO [db1].[dbo].Subscriber (SubscriberGUID, ItemGUID_Entity, SubscriberID, SubscriberRegionID, SubscriberTypeID, ID, SubscriberNameFull, SubscriberEmail, SubscriberLogin, SubscriberPassword, Active, DateCreated, DateDeleted)
    SELECT 
        SubscriberGUID, ItemGUID_Entity, SubscriberID, SubscriberRegionID, 
        SubscriberTypeID, ID, SubscriberNameFull, SubscriberEmail, 
        SubscriberLogin, SubscriberPassword, Active, DateCreated, DateDeleted
    FROM [db2].[dbo].SubScriber

PRINT 'Successfully Re-imported data from SubScriber backup'

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [db1].[dbo].MsSubscriber OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* wanted to get out of writing the column list, you could use dynamic SQL

```sql
DECLARE @cols1 nvarchar(max), @cols2 nvarchar(max);

SELECT
    @cols1 = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c1.name, ',')) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c1.name),
    @cols2 = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c2.name, ',')) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c1.name) -- same order
FROM db1.sys.columns c1
JOIN db2.sys.columns c2
WHERE c1.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[db1].[dbo].Subscriber')
  AND c2.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[db2].[dbo].Subscriber');

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [db1].[dbo].Subscriber ON;

INSERT INTO [db1].[dbo].Subscriber
(' + @cols1 + N')
    SELECT 
        ' + @cols2 + N'
    FROM [db2].[dbo].SubScriber;

PRINT ''Successfully Re-imported data from SubScriber backup'';

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [db1].[dbo].Subscriber OFF;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```